# display the active member details

Tags: sql-server

I have one database which contains username, password and IsActive (data type is "bit")  columns.

My requirement is that I have to display the user details when the user name and password is correct and when the active column of that user is true.

How can I check these 3 columns in Sql Server 2005?

Comment: Are we talking about an SQL query or from C#?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - if you we're looking for an SQL query, why tag it as C#?

Comment: Edited the post, and removed the C# tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like the following?

```
SELECT username, password 
FROM UsersTable
WHERE IsActive > 0 AND username = 'admin' AND password = '1234'
```